# Set tickInterval in format HH:mm am/pm of a HIChart's Line chart using Swift 5.0

Tags: ios, swift, highcharts

I want to set intervals as per the below image. I have tried to set using it below code.

```
    let xAxis = HIXAxis()
    xAxis.type = "datetime"
    xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats = HIDateTimeLabelFormats()
    xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.day = HIDay()
    xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.day.main = "%l:%M"
    xAxis.min = NSNumber(value: ConverteddateFrom ) //Millisecond 12 AM midnight from starting of the day
    xAxis.max = NSNumber(value: ConverteddateEnd) //Millisecond 12 AM to end of the day
    xAxis.tickInterval =  NSNumber(value: 4 * 3600 * 1000 )
    xAxis.categories = DateList
    options.xAxis = [xAxis]

    let plotoptions = HIPlotOptions()
    plotoptions.series = HISeries()
    plotoptions.series.label = HILabel()
    plotoptions.series.label.connectorAllowed = NSNumber(value: false)    
   //     plotoptions.series.pointStart = 12
   //     plotoptions.series.pointInterval = NSNumber(value: 4)
   //     plotoptions.series.pointIntervalUnit = "AM"

    options.plotOptions = plotoptions

    let line1 = HILine()
    line1.name = "Phase B"
    line1.data =  PhaseBList

    let line2 = HILine()
    line2.name = "Phase R"
    line2.data =  PhaseRList

    let line3 = HILine()
    line3.name = "Phase Y"
    line3.data =  PhaseYList

    options.series = [line1, line2, line3]
    options.responsive = responsive
    options.colors = ["#7CB5EC","#F94F6C", "#FFB647"]

    inputVoltage.options = options
```

but I didn't get proper x-axis with intervals. can anybody help me on this?

[image]

I am getting on x-axis points something like starting point as 20:00 to 16:00 with interval of 4 hours. I am expecting it from 12Am to 12Am. Also I can't see the data on graph.

[image]

Comment: and what did you get?

Comment: @Lu_ Thanks for the comment I have updated the code and changes with what I am getting. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution -

1 - The problem was with the data presenting. Initially I was added the data array only whereas we have to add data along with its correspondence date. So it becomes array of array like this -

```
line1.data = [
    [1562106600000, 0],
    [1562121000000, 0.25]
]
```

2 - x axis time from 20:00 to 16:00 is because of UTC time. Solution is :

```
 options.time = HITime()
 options.time.useUTC =  false
 //options.time.timezone = "Asia/Kolkata" // If you want to set timezon you can
```

3 - converting the date into AM/PM in 12 hrs format.

```
xAxis.type = "datetime"
xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats = HIDateTimeLabelFormats()
xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.hour = HIHour()
xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.hour.main = "%l %P"
xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.day = HIDay()
xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.day.main = "%l %P"
xAxis.min = NSNumber(value: ConverteddateFrom ) //Millisecond 12 AM midnight from starting of the day

xAxis.max = NSNumber(value: ConverteddateEnd) //Millisecond 12 AM midnight from ending of the day

xAxis.tickInterval =  NSNumber(value: 4 * 3600 * 1000 )
options.xAxis = [xAxis]
```

This is how my graph is looking now - 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 hour tick interval, so probably you need to change `dateTimeLabelFormats` from `day` to `hour`:

```
xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats = HIDateTimeLabelFormats()
xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.hour = HIHour()
xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.hour.main = "%l %P"
xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.day = HIDay()
xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.day.main = "%l %P"
```

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/ios/highcharts/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there I have got 3 July at start point & at the end 4 July instead of getting midnight 12am at the both ends. Any idea on this?

Comment: Hi @Tejas Ratunawar - Please try the code from the updated answer.